# How to manage the hierarchy of State in Functional Programming?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, scalaz, scala-cats

Say I have a `Student` class which has lots of actions:

```scala
final case class Student(name: String, knowledge: List[String]) {
  def learn(item: String) : Student = this.copy(knowledge = knowledge :+ item)
}
```

Here you can notice that this class is not influenced by any outer State.

But if I put this class into a Stateful environment(like a `School`):

```scala
final case class School(students: Map[String, Student]) {
  def learn(studentName: String, item: String) : State[School, Student] = State {
    oldSchool => {
      val oldStudent = students.get(studentName).getOrElse(Student(studentName, List()))
      val newStudent = oldStudent.learn(item)
      oldSchool.copy(students = students + (studentName -> newStudent)) -> newStudent
    }
  }
}
```

And then I cannot use `student.learn(info)` directly, for `Student` even doesn't know the environment(`School` class) exists. So if I want to call the actions of a student, I have to call the `proxy function` exposed by the Environment class. If I have lots of actions in `Student`, I **HAVE TO** write the same count of proxy functions in `School`, which is frustrating and not fun at all.

Any advices? How to manage this kind of State hierarchy?

Comment: Simply abstract the manipulation away, so make a function `updateStudent (...)`, where you pass a function that can update the student in whatever way you want.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem But if the `Student` class has lots of actions with various parameters, then the `updateStudent` will become another `School`, which has to deal with different kinds of parameters and dispatch params to suitable actions of `Student`

Comment: no you should use *partial application* here. In Haskell for example one can use `updateSchool "StudentName" (learn "someItem") someSchool` to update `someSchool` such that a student with `"StudentName"` learns `"someItem"`.

Comment: See [partial application in Scala](https://danielwestheide.com/blog/2013/01/30/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-11-currying-and-partially-applied-functions.html).

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by @WillemVanOnsem, here is my solution.

```scala
  def updateStudent: String => (Student => Student) => School =
    name =>
      func =>
        this.copy(
          students = students + (name -> func(
            students.get(name).getOrElse(Student(name, List()))
          ))
        )
```

And the usage likes:

```scala
    val stu1   = Student("name1", List())
    val school = School(Map(stu1.name -> stu1))

    val newSchool = school.updateStudent("name1") { student =>
      student.learn("someItem")
    }
```

And I notice that if your hierarchy is really deep, the `(Student => Student)` part can be replaced by Lens, so the you should prepare a bunch of Lens, rather than a bunch of Proxy Functions of different depth of functions, cool!

Comment: I'd rewrite it as just `def updateStudent(name: String, func: (Student => Student)): School`. Using multiparameter functions instead of currying doesn't make you code less functional and does add readability.

Comment: And if you decide to proceed with currying it should be `val` instead of `def`. `def` would allocate a function object on each call for no reason.

Comment: Allocate a new object? Could you please explain it in more detail?

Comment: `name => ...` is a sugar for `new Function1{override def apply(name: String) { ...`